# AJAX call to server side function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and I'm not too clear about how to use the format of the AJAX call
ex

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/function",
    data: '{ searchBy: id }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).success(function (result) {
    alert(result);
})
```

I have a function in the `.cs` file that should take in a string ID and return a list of all the objects that contain that ID.
I want to call this function in the javascript to check that the returned list is null (therefore the ID does not already exist) before inserting new objects into the database.
How could I go about doing this?
All the examples I see return a `string` from the server side function.

Comment: Serialization is your friend. Return some format that allows you to interpret if the data is a string or number or array or object or null. There are several ways to do this. Traditionally you'd return XML (the X in ajaX). Most people these days return JSON.

Comment: you want to check if the list is null inside the `success` callback? If so, just check if `result === null` ?

Comment: You can't call functions on the server from javascript, all you can do is visit an URL.

Comment: @jonathanGB that seems the most efficient way. I'm not too sure about how to set up the call yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control of the server-side endpoint, then return whatever you want to indicate no matches - an empty list, null, empty string, etc.  Then in the success function check for that.

Note the `dataType` ajax parameter.  That tells the ajax function how to format the response for you to consume.  If you are expecting JSON to be returned, use `dataType: json` and in the `success` function check for an empty json array `result.length === 0`.  In the case of null or empty string, use a `dataType: text` and check for `result == "null"` or `result == ""`. Etc.

If you don't have control of server side then you will need to conform to whatever data it sends back to you.  The `dataType` is still the key though.

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
public static int function(int Id) 
{
    return Id;
}
```

Comment: why is this returning int?

Answer (score 0):

If you need use only ajax, the best option is [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest), is Vanilla JS and more fast.

If you decide use ajax with jquery the function is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/function",
    data: { searchBy: id },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the syntax for the `url:` field? Is the `.aspx.` page the current page and the function name?

Comment: the url can be "url: a_cross_domain_url" or "url: '/Default.aspx/function'", with the second option, request use current page domain.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done C#, but your `url` parameter must be a path to a file (e.g. `url: Default.aspx`). In your file, you should have the logic to handle the request and call the right function. This function will check the DB, and will print the result.

```
// inside Default.aspx
// 1- is there a POST parameter? If so, call foo()

public static string foo(string postParam) {
    // check DB, process
    Print(result)
}
```

Inside your `success` callback, check if null:

```
.then(function(result) {
    if (result === null) // do stuff
})
```